# KOMA-Script ‘fontsize’ with ‘newtxmath’: ‘microtype’ custom protrusion settings not working

Tags: fontsize, koma-script, microtype, newtxmath, protrusion

I want to use `scrbook` with `fontsize=12pt`. To get Linux Libertine with matching math, I use the `newtxmath` package. I wanted to set up `microtype` margin protrusion for footnote markers and it didn't take effect. After a few hours I developed this MWE to identify the problematic parts:

```
\documentclass[%
fontsize=12pt % critical line 1
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{newtxmath} % critical line 2

\usepackage{microtype}

\SetProtrusion{
    encoding={*},
    family={LinuxLibertineT-TLF},
    series={*},
    size={5,6,7,8}
}{1={ ,1000}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent-A% Testing hyphen protrusion
    \hfill
    e\(\mathrm{e}\)% does text match with math?
    \footnote{blah}% footnote marker protrusion?
\end{document}
```

The right margin area depending on the two critical lines:

[image: outputs]

I’d like to have the 12 pt fontsize, matching math font and footnote marker protrusion together. The `-A` in the document shows that regular protrusion works in all cases. Are my `microtype` protrusion settings even fully valid? I’m never sure on them and I’m more or less guessing there.

Comment: newtxmath changes the math sizes. \sf@size (used by the superscript) has now size 8.8 and not 8. So you need to add this value to the size declaration: `    size={5,6,7,8,8.8} `.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thanks, it worked. You can write this as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`newtxmath` changes the math sizes. `\sf@size` (used by the superscript) has now size 8.8 and not 8. So you need to add this value to the size declaration:

```
 size={5,6,7,8,8.8}
```

or use a size range:

```
 size={5-9}
```

(the last number has to be greater than `8.8` because `microtype` won't include the upper limit in the range itself)

Comment: Do you know why `size={*}` doesn't work? Is `*` just not effective for `size`?

Comment: `*` is imho only \normalsize, use `size={-}` for all sizes.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. That seems strange, but Microtype often seems strange to me. ;)

Comment: @cfr `*` always stands for "default", not for "any" (the choice of the asterisk has been somewhat unfortunate, I know...)